# How to store conditional data in a range in an array and write it on a new column in a worksheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am setting up a bookkeeping system using excel-vba to automatically send different values on the journal to specific accounts such as the ledger, balance sheet, income statement, etc based on category or description.

This is my first attempt to automate these accounts.

''''''

```
Sub ListSpecificVals()

    Dim Arr() As Variant
    Dim datarange, cell As Range
    Dim count As Long

    Set datarange = Sheet5.Range("a17:f28")
    ReDim Arr(1 To 12, 1 To 6)

    count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(datarange, "abc")
    MsgBox count

    For i = 1 To count
        For Each cell In datarange
            If cell.Value = "abc" Then
                cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = 33
                For i = 1 To count
                    Arr(i, 1) = cell.Address
                Next i
                Debug.Print cell.Address + " = "
                Debug.Print cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If
        Next cell
    For i = 1 To count
        Sheet5.Cells(i + 16, 10).Value = Arr
    Next i

End Sub
```

''''

When writing the array values to the worksheet I expect each cell on the result range to give each different cell address for the cells containing "abc" in "datarange". Instead, only the last cell.address in "datarange" is written on every cell on the results range on the worksheet.
Again, when I use Debug.Print cell.Address + " = ", 
Debug.Print cell.Offset(0, 1).Value as shown in the code, the immediate windows shows the results perfectly and exactly as they should come out, but when I use Debug.Print Arr(i,1) the immediate window does not show any results.

Comment: This code not even compile because of the variable i is inside another loops with the same variable i , Can you be more specific about what do you want to do ? You want to run a range and get the address of the column in the right when the cell have "abc" on value ?

Comment: It's really not clear what the expected outcome is, or why you're looping multiple times over all of the cells in `datarange`

Comment: Within the "datarange", there are 9 cells whose value is "abc". These cells are scattered all over the "datarange". The results column spans 9 rows, corresponding to those number of "abc" cells in the "datarange". I want each cell in the results column on the worksheet to show the cell address of one of the "abc" cells in the "datarange". The problem here is that the results range gets populated with only one cell address throughout, which is the last cell address in the "datarange". On the other hand, the immediate window shows all nine cell addresses correctly.

Comment: The target column on the worksheet shows these results:$C$26
$C$26
$C$26
$C$26
$C$26
$C$26
$C$26
$C$26
$C$26

Comment: The immediate window outputs these results (which is what I expect to see on the target column on the worksheet): $A$17 = 
 33 
$C$17 = 
 33 
$E$17 = 
 33 
$B$18 = 
 33 
$D$21 = 
 33 
$B$22 = 
 33 
$D$24 = 
 33 
$A$26 = 
 33 
$C$26 = 
 33

Comment: Please note, the first  For i = 1 To count line on top of the datarange For Each .. Next loop has been commented out on my code. Please ignore it.